# Selecting list items by id without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have a list in html of this type

```
<ul>
 <li id="1.1" fatherid="1"> ...</li>
 <li id="1.2" fatherid="1"> ...</li>
 <li id="1.3" fatherid="1"> ...</li>
 ...
</ul>
```

And I want to select all the items of the list with a given fatherid. For example I'd like to select all the items with "1" as fatherid, but I don't know how to do it. I tried with querySelectorAll and getElementById but it didn't work, and I prefer not to use jquery.
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Do you want to do it with simple javascript?

Comment: @DiesanRomero I'd prefer, but it's not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`Document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) accepts a selector we can make use of the CSS [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```js
const r = document.querySelectorAll('li[fatherid="1"]');
console.log(Array.from(r));
```

```html
<ul>
 <li id="1.1" fatherid="1"> ...</li>
 <li id="1.2" fatherid="1"> ...</li>
 <li id="1.3" fatherid="1"> ...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use data-attributes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the fatherids (which is the recommended way to add custom attributes to html elements). You can then find the tags with a given fatherid using the `[data-fatherid]` selector.

```js
  function getByFather(id) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(`[data-fatherid='${id}']`);
  }
  
  console.log([...getByFather(1)]);
  console.log([...getByFather(2)]);
```

```html
<ul>
 <li id="1.1" data-fatherid="1">1.1</li>
 <li id="1.2" data-fatherid="1">1.2</li>
 <li id="1.3" data-fatherid="1">1.3</li>
 
 <li id="2.1" data-fatherid="2">2.1</li>
 <li id="2.2" data-fatherid="2">2.2</li>
</ul>
```